# use Inline CPP to call function in so file not working

Tags: c++, perl, shared-libraries

i have .h and .cpp file:

say_hi.h:

```
   extern "C" {
      void say_hi();
   }
```

say_hi.cpp:

```
   #include <cstdio>
   #include "say_hi.h"
   void say_hi(){
   printf("hello workd!\n");
   }
```

then i compile this with

```
g++ -I. -fPIC -c *.cpp
g++ -shared *.o -I. -olibsay_hi.so
```

then use perl Inline CPP to call it:

```
>perl -e 'use Inline CPP=>q{  \
 #include "say_hi.h" \
 void test(){return say_hi(); } \
 }, INC=>"-I.",LIBS=>"-lsay_hi"; test()'
```

Here I got:

```
perl: symbol lookup error: /home/xxx/test_so/_Inline/lib/auto/e_8555/e_8555.so: undefined symbol: say_hi
```

But if I test the .so file with below .cpp file
test.cpp:

```
#include "say_hi.h"
main() {
  say_hi();
}
```

Compile it:

```
g++ -L. -lsay_hi test.cpp -o test
```

Run the test:

```
>test
hello workd!
```

Is there something wrong with my Perl (v5.8.0), or did I miss anything?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `void say_hi()` implementation is not into `extern "C"`...

Comment: Thanks Jarod42 for your reply, in real life say_hi() funcion can be any style of code, which already compiled into .so, my understanding is only in .h file it need to be declared as extern "C", that's why my pure call from test.cpp works, the problem is not with .so, but in perl Inline CPP i think.

Comment: Problem Solved by using   
    `MYEXTLIB => '/full/path_to/libsay_hi.so'` 
    instead of 
    `LIBS=>"-l..."`
More details check [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1069902)

Comment: @codesoar you should add this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by using `MYEXTLIB => '/full/path_to/libsay_hi.so'` instead of `LIBS=>"-l..."` More details check [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1069902)

Comment: You should put the more details here.